# Как передать аргумент и получить результат из программы?

Tags: c#, процесс

Написал простенькое консольное приложение которая на вход принимает один аргумент. Путь к картинке. Из консоли можно ее вызвать так

`app.exe image.jpg`
Также в программе app.exe я сделал вывод `Console.Write(data);`

Теперь пытаюсь из c# кода запустить этот процесс и хочу результат занести в переменную

```
  var process = new Process
            {
                StartInfo =
                {
                    FileName = "app.exe",
                    Arguments = "1.JPG"
                }
            };
            process.Start();
            using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
            {
                string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                Console.Write(result);
            }
```

У меня выводит ошибку

`StandardOut has not been redirected or the process hasn't started yet.`

Comment: [ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx)

Comment: то же самое,,,,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput(v=vs.110).aspx) описано подробнее. Ваш код надо дополнить 2мя строками и тогда будет работать.

```
var process = new Process
{
    StartInfo =
    {
        FileName = "app.exe",
        RedirectStandardOutput = true, 
        UseShellExecute = false,
        Arguments = "1.JPG"
    }
};
process.Start();
using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
{
    string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
    Console.Write(result);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте вторую часть кода модифицировать следующим образом:

```
process.Start();
while (!process.StandardOutput.EndOfStream) {
    string line = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```